# Can you use a colon to introduce just a single item instead of a list?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, lists, colons

Colons are usually used to introduce a list of some kind after an independent clause; however, would it work for a single item? For example, can you write

> For 3 years, I ate hamburgers: my friend's favorite food.

If you do not use a colon here, what should be used?

Comment: It’s fine to use a colon to separate sentences into clauses like that and to lend emphasis to the final part. But stylistically I’d recommend a bit of an inversion: *For three years, I ate my friend’s favorite food: hamburgers*.

Comment: @DanBron That sounds a bit cruel. What did your friend eat?

Comment: @DanBron "My friend's favorite food" is not a clause but rather a noun phrase in apposition.

Comment: @tchrist I'm in apposition to having my syntactic analysis corrected, 'clause it makes me look like I don't know what i'm talking about.

Comment: You should use a comma.

Comment: While the structure is fine I do not believe we would consider it a one item list

Comment: Semicolons: we use them every day.

Answer (score 3):

*The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) offers a usefully concise (but somewhat oddly punctuated) discussion of the colon at section 5.5:

> **5.5 Colon**
>
> The colon points forward: from a premise to a conclusion, from a cause to an effect, from an introduction to a main point; from a general statement to an example. It fulfills the same function as words such as *namely*, *that is*, *as*, *for example*, *for instance*, *because*, *as follows*, and *therefore*:
>
> [Relevant example:] She had but one hobby: chocolate.

Various U.S. style guides adopt essentially the same view of the colon that Oxford does. All of them approve of the use of a colon to set off phrases such as the one in your example:

> For three years, I ate hamburgers: my friend's favorite food.

Or, in Dan Bron's preferred formulation:

> For three years, I ate my friend's favorite food: hamburgers.

Alternative punctuation options include an em dash:

> For three years, I ate hamburgers—my friend's favorite food.

a comma:

> For three years, I ate hamburgers, my friend's favorite food.

and (arguably) parentheses:

> For three years, I ate hamburgers (my friend's favorite food).

Comment: While a comma and en em dash can perform as alternatives there are certainly differences and reasons to not equate them. +1 but a good answer should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use colons for other uses besides a listing.  In your example the colon indicates a more detailed answer or explanation will shortly follow.  The colon relates clauses or indicates there is a close connection to what is before and after the colon mark.  Before the colon you must have a complete sentence and many people miss that portion.  You could just put a period there but the colon shows  --a connection similar to a semi colon.  With the semi colon two complete sentences must be present instead of one.